# for word ending with s/ or s sound, when do we omit extra s n when don't?

Tags: grammar, apostrophe

I've just started  reading 'Writing in the technical field' by Thorsten Ewald and in it, it was written for the possessive of words ending with s( or s sound) you can choose to add s or not ( most commonly not)
and then in examples, he has used
The class’s performance was dismal.
The ladies’ room is on the right, the gentlemen’s is on the left.
Iris’s house.
so, how are we gonna know when to add an extra s?

Comment: [it says, not it was written]. :) Please do not use gonna here or we'll end up with text messages. Also, please amend your answer to say: the possessive of words ending in s. Thanks.

Comment: Nobody normally enunciates possessive **'s** after a *plural* ending with **s** such as *the **ladies'** room*. Almost no-one calls the male toilets "the gentlemen's" anyway (it's invariably ***the gents***), as per [this usage chart.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+gents+is%2Cthe+gent%27s+is%2Cthe+gents%27+is%2Cthe+gents%27s+is%2Cthe+gentlemens+is%2Cthe+gentlemen%27s+is&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) The idea of a "choice" applies with, say, *Saint James'[s] Park*, which may be written with (nothing) or **'** or **'s** (pronounced in the *last* case).

Comment: @Lambie This is the _Learners_ channel. You can expect people who ask questions here to not be perfectly fluent. And getting a good grasp for style levels (going to vs. gonna) is one of the harder parts of learning a language.

Comment: @Divizna I don't expect perfection but it is a good idea to know the name of what you are asking, right?

Comment: @Lambie Sure. And I don't mind you correcting the asker. My issue with it was that it seemed to lack explanation. If you told me "change your question to say [string of words I don't understand]", it wouldn't help me but just confuse me. I think it's better to assume that the askers here are trying but may just not know the proper term (yet - let's enlighten 'em), or that "gonna" is quite informal (not text message, btw, it's the correct spelling, much older than a cellphone), rather than think they're just being sloppy, and your comment gave me a bit of a vibe of the latter. That's all.

Comment: @Divizna I put grammar corrections in square brackets so they can make the corrections themselves. And comments are meant for clarifying things, here, the possessive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the word in question is a plural, it's always apostrophe only. (parents' house)

If it isn't, it gets complicated, basically down to custom established for that individual word, and there are often both variants.

If it's a person's name, then modern names usually add *s* (Charles's bag), and ancient names usually don't (Socrates' teaching).

Note that the "extra" *s* is not only written but also pronounced (as a distinct syllable if it would otherwise bleed in the preceding word's end).

Answer (score 0):

The general rule is to spell it the way it would naturally be pronounced.
If the spelling and pronunciation don't match, at least one of them is wrong (or historical usage).

- If a singular noun ends in "s":

  - add `es` to make it plural.  E.g. "*The Joneses will*", "*the glasses are*".
  - add `'s` to make it possessive. E.g. "*the lens's*", "*Dennis's dog*".

  In each case an extra syllable is added to the pronunciation.
- If a plural noun ends in "s":

  - add only the apostrophe, without the "s" to make it possessive.
  - e.g. "*one glass*", "*two glasses*", "*both glasses' contents*", but not "*both glasses's contents*".

  Only one extra syllable is added to the pronunciation of the singular form, not two.

Comment: "Spell it the way you pronounce it" seems to be good advice for a child learning to write what they already know how to say, but I doubt its usefulness for a learner of a second language who usually isn't sure about the spoken form either (in fact, it's typical for second language learners and even fluent users to be more confident with writing).